# Sony Bravia TV KD-55AF8: install HTML5 app?

Tags: android, html, sony, television

I just found out that I can run an html5 app from a USB key on my Sony Bravia TV. I tried out the "show a website" app and it actually works:
https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/app/samples/index.html
However, I was not able to install it on my TV. This kind of code does not seem to work:

```
{
 "action": "copyapp",
  "auid": "net.sony.tv.sample.myapp_1",
  "copyapp": {
    "app": "net.sony.tv.sample.myapp_1",
  }
}
```

Now, considering that the TV will load an HTML5 app from a USB key, is there any way to sideload it?

Comment: so the TV is running Android? Can you get to the settings menu and enable developer mode? If yes, then sideloading: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#Enabling

Comment: Hi Blundell, thank you for asking. Yes, the TV is running android, and I can sideload apks. The problem is that an html5 "app" does not come in the apk format. It is just a directory with a bunch of files. apparently you can install it by editing the  autorun.txt file: https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/app/install/index.html but that does not seem to work.

Comment: ah I see. Could you side load an apk, that has code to push the html files into the right directory? :-)

Comment: that could be a way. Anyway, the code to push the app is the one I posted, only it does not get executed (that is the code for a Bravia monitor, I am talking about a TV). The strange thing is that the "show a website" app for the Bravia monitor works with the auto-run code on the TV, but when I put in the copy app code (with the right app name, of course) nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah so perhaps the USB stick has permission to execute, but doesn't have permission to write to a different drive. Pure guess but maybe if you push an APK it will be on the same drive, so could have write permission.

Comment: My guess is that something in the Bravia TV system locks the possibilities to install hrml5 "apps"... maybe there is some system tweak to apply but I have no idea what that might be...

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/app/getting-started/#case-1-show-a-web-site

And this :

```
USB: /sony/
          +--- autorun.txt
          +--- apps/webapps/manifestjson_weburl/app/manifest.json
```

You need to put your app in a `sony` folder at the USB root.